# Excel formula to compute IRR by looking up first non-zero cell and then the date corresponding to the first non zero cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Looking for a formula I can enter in column B that will compute for the IRR of the data set. As the IRR formula is =XIRR(Values,Dates,guess[]), i am looking for a way to have it automated where in the formula cell reference starts at the first non-zero cell (for the values) and then the same corresponding cell in the dates.

Appreciate any help that can be offered. I have a sample picture at the link below and as you can see the starting cell reference varies given that the first non-zero cell also changes but I need to find a way to have this automatically referenced and have a uniform formula for the entire column B.

[image: Sample Format in Excel Here]

Answer (score 0):

I've got a way of doing this that uses a mix of INDIRECT, ADDRESS and MATCH and it looks like this for row 2:

```
=XIRR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+MATCH(TRUE,D2:O2<>0,0))&":O"&ROW()),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()+MATCH(TRUE,D2:O2<>0,0))&":O1"))
```

I'll try and break this down for you. First of all we need to work out which is the first column that is non-zero, we can do this quite easily with something like:

```
MATCH(TRUE,D2:O2<>0,0)
```

This returns a number that we can then use elsewhere. What we need to do is use this number to define the range that the XIRR uses. I find the easiest way to do this is to use ADDRESS like this:

```
ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+MATCH(TRUE,D2:O2<>0,0))
```

I've had to add `COLUMN()` in there first so that we know where we are now, and how much further to offset. This only gives us the first half of the range which is G2. So we also need to add on `:` and the end part of the address so we add a bit more (note that here the O column to end on is hardcoded) and put it all into an `INDIRECT` wrapper.

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+MATCH(TRUE,D2:O2<>0,0))&":O"&ROW())
```

This is a semi-dynamic way of getting `G2:O2`. There's then a comparable formula for getting the `G1:O1` but now even more of it is hardcoded in

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()+MATCH(TRUE,D2:O2<>0,0))&":O1")
```

Combine the two INDIRECT within the XIRR and you should be good to go.

This version of the formula will only work when your data ends in column O, that the data to look for non-zero values always starts in the column directly after the formula, and that your dates are in row 1. All of these can be overcome and make the formula fully dynamic but that would make it even more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you show no version constraints in your tags, the following should work, and is non-volatile since it does not use the `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` functions.

Rather we use `INDEX` and `XMATCH` to return the relevant arrays of dates and values.

Use of the `LET` function results in a more easily understood formula.

```
B2: =LET(
    arrDt, $D$1:$O$1,
    arrVal, $D2:$O2,
    startCol, XMATCH(
        TRUE,
        arrVal <> 0
    ),
    dts, INDEX(
        arrDt,
        SEQUENCE(
            ,
            COLUMNS(arrDt) -
                startCol + 1,
            startCol
        )
    ),
    vals, INDEX(
        arrVal,
        SEQUENCE(
            ,
            COLUMNS(arrDt) -
                startCol + 1,
            startCol
        )
    ),
    XIRR(vals, dts)
)
```

and fill down.

[image]